# Ubuntu GNOME - Tried KDE. Deleted it and now autoremove shows alot of used files

Tags: gnome

So I´m running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04. So I wanted to try KDE plasma desktop, i installed it through the terminal. I personally didn´t like KDE. I removed KDE from my machine. But now everytime I run a full-upgrade command, it shows alot of packages that are ¨no longer needed¨ and can be removed. I personally don´t trust this because it has alot of files in it that are used by GNOME aswell.

How can I fix this so it excludes those packages in autoremove?

apt-get update output file:

http://pastebin.com/YC2W6uhQ

Comment: And those packages are? How did you remove KDE? Can you please share the output of apt update?

Comment: I did not want to remove GNOME. I want to remove KDE. GNOME is my main DE, i installed KDE just to try out.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YC2W6uhQ - Output of apt-update

Comment: How do you know _gnome_ uses those files ?

Comment: I don't see any mention of _gnome_ in there. When you do an _update_ does the system suggest you remove those files ?

Comment: Because when I installed KDE, the terminal  said that it need 330 MB of space on the HDD. Now autoremove says it will clean up 450 MB, which is not the size of KDE itself. The 120 MB has to be some type of file used by my current DE.

Comment: When i run update, then system suggests me to remove those files.

Comment: Please edit your question when adding more info. I see there only me and qt components, nothing related to gnome or GTK. The extra space might be related to unused kernels, did you recently receoved Kernel updates?

Comment: I am aware of the linux kernel listed there, as I updated the kernel about a week ago.

Comment: You know you can test *any* DE by just booting a live session, don't you? The hint is a suggestion for the future. Avoid installing additional DEs, especially when later you personally don't like them and try to remove what can't be easily removed (DEs are very complex and depend on way too many packages seamlessly integrated. Bottom line: When you install an additional DE you can't really uninstall it. It's fine to play with but for your own sake do NOT do it in a production machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you update kernel Ubuntu will suggest to remove older package by `apt autoremove`, that's why total freed space is bigger than KDE's size, you can remove all of those and safely call `sudo apt autoremove`.

Comment: @ByteCommander It does, read the comments and list of packages to remove.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I missed that. Please excuse.